# creating matrix of a special form and an out of bound error in R

Tags: r, matrix, error-handling

I have vector of length k filled with values of a parameter rho. let name this vector rho.vec()
I want to create multiple matrices of form below for each of the elements of vector rho.vec().
[image]

this is my code for this:

```
    mat<- matrix(0,n,n)
f=1
for(i in 1:k){
  for(ro in 1:n){
    for(co in 0:(n-f)){
      mat[ro,co+f]<- rho.vec[i]^co
    }
    f<- f+1
  }
mat[lower.tri(mat)] = t(mat)[lower.tri(mat)]

}
```

but I get error : **Error in `[<-`(`*tmp*`, ro, co + f, value = rho.vec[i]^co) :
subscript out of bounds**

I tried it for 5*5 simple matrix and it worked. but I m not getting the result here for my loop code. any idea or hint for this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are two ways to do what you want. One produces an array containing the matrices and the other produces a list of matrices:

```
rho.vec <- c(.4, .5, .6, .7, .8, .9)
nrho <- length(rho.vec)
n <- 5
mat <- array(1, dim=c(n, n, length(rho.vec)))
```

This sets up an array in which each page is a matrix:

```
for (i in seq(nrho)){
    low <- unlist(mapply(seq, 1, (n - 1):1))
    up <- unlist(mapply(seq, 1:(n - 1), 1))
    lower <- rho.vec[i]^low
    upper <- rho.vec[i]^up
    mat[, , i][lower.tri(mat[, , i])] <- lower
    mat[, , i][upper.tri(mat[, , i])] <- upper
}
```

Here's the first page with rho = .4

```
mat[, , 1]
#        [,1]  [,2] [,3]  [,4]   [,5]
# [1,] 1.0000 0.400 0.16 0.064 0.0256
# [2,] 0.4000 1.000 0.40 0.160 0.0640
# [3,] 0.1600 0.400 1.00 0.400 0.1600
# [4,] 0.0640 0.160 0.40 1.000 0.4000
# [5,] 0.0256 0.064 0.16 0.400 1.0000
```

The second approach creates a function and then uses `lapply`:

```
symm <- function(rho, n) {
    m <- matrix(1, n, n)
    low <- unlist(mapply(seq, 1, (n - 1):1))
    up <- unlist(mapply(seq, 1:(n - 1), 1))
    lower <- rho^low
    upper <- rho^up
    m[lower.tri(m)] <- lower
    m[upper.tri(m)] <- upper    
    return(m)
}

mat.list <- lapply(rho.vec, symm, n=n)
mat.list[[1]]
#        [,1]  [,2] [,3]  [,4]   [,5]
# [1,] 1.0000 0.400 0.16 0.064 0.0256
# [2,] 0.4000 1.000 0.40 0.160 0.0640
# [3,] 0.1600 0.400 1.00 0.400 0.1600
# [4,] 0.0640 0.160 0.40 1.000 0.4000
# [5,] 0.0256 0.064 0.16 0.400 1.0000
```

Comment: It worked perfectly! however, any idea why my code is not working when I repeat it in i in 1:k loop?

Comment: You have two issues in your nested loops. First the error is triggered because you do not reset f <- 1 when you begin a new matrix. The `f <- 1` line should be inside the outer loop just after `for(i in 1:k){`. Second you do not print out any results or save each matrix, so after the code finishes, you have only the last matrix stored in `mat`.